# Probabilistic Robotics

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Would questions on probabilistic robotics be appropriate here or better suited for a different StackExchange site like `Mathematics.SE`?

I have some questions on the theories but also on setting up the sensors and range finders.

Comment: Keep it coming. Love probabilistic robotics

Answer (score 3):

If a question is *essentially* a robotics question then it is welcome here, even if it is also on topic for aother site. You are correct though that some types of questions *might* be better placed on other sites.

Having said that, we do already have a variety of questions with the tags [kalman-filter](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kalman-filter), [slam](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slam) and  [particle-filter](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-filter), so there are already experts here who are interested in the kinds of topics that the book [Probabilistic Robotics](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org) covers.